# How do I simply make my JSON data accessible by my script?

Tags: javascript, json

My directory goes like that

```
app/
  index.html
  script.js
  data.json
```

Sounds good? Now, I would like to choose a random object from my JSON data and present it to the user each time my document is loaded, good? Now I have a problem at that first part of it, getting the data from my `data.json` in the most optimal way possible. I can add an XMLHttpRequest() in my `script.js` to fetch the contents of my `data.json` or I would even use the fetch API, but I understand that these are made for "fetching" data across the web and are considered some sort of an overkill for such a simple task, I mean you don't need to send an HTTP request to link your CSS with your HTML, do you? So I figured out there must be a way to do that easily, one answer I found out there was to link your data as so `<script id="data" src="./data.json" type="application/json"></script>` and then you can `document.getElementById("data")` it, but that didn't work for me for some reason, one workaround that I came with was to change my `data.json` to `data.js` and just add a `var data =` prefix to my whole JSON data and then import that to my `index.html` and now I can access the variable `data` from my script, but I feel this is too hacky and isn't/shouldn't be the optimal to go around this. I think this scratches the topic of CORS/Same-origin which is a concept I have a feeble grasp on. A detailed explanation of what is going on in here would be greatly appreciated :)

EDIT: The answers provided speak solely of the fetch API, my issue is why is an HTTP request required to get access to a local file? why can't we link the JSON data through a link tag just like everything else e.g. our HTML, CSS, JS which are all linked using link/script tags.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative paths with fetch in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36369082/relative-paths-with-fetch-in-javascript)

Comment: This is actually interesting explanation in there.

Comment: But irrelevant to my question.

Comment: What's the type of you project? Is `app` a simple Apache folder that serves static data? Is this a Node.js project? JavaScript can't access on the local hard-disk by default. Node.js offers some addition APIs that [let you do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011011/using-node-js-how-do-i-read-a-json-file-into-server-memory). Depending on you type of project, there might be different solutions.

Comment: It is just a basic static server, no Node.js involved, with `app/` being the root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come up with the three approaches below:

### 1) Fetch (or XHR) the `.json` file

I'd definitely regard using the `Fetch API` (or `XHR`) as the standard approach to enable a web document to retrieve a `.json` file from the server.

```
fetch('/app/data.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json));
```

### 2) Reference a `.js` file instead of a `.json` file

**ie.** *Use `'/app/my-json-data.js'` instead of `'/app/data.json'`*

As you correctly point out in your question, you could upload a `.js` file to your server instead of a `.json` file, where, if your original JSON file `'/app/data.json'` looked like this:

```
{"Name" : "Data", "Section 1" : {"A" : "a", "B" : "b"}, "Section 2" : ["C", "D"]}
```

then your JS file `'/app/my-json-data.js'` would look like this, instead:

```
let myJSONData = '{"Name" : "Data", "Section 1" : {"A" : "a", "B" : "b"}, "Section 2" : ["C", "D"]}';
```

Then you could retrieve that JSON string into your document using:

```
<script src="/app/my-json-data.js"></script>
```

after which the string would exist in the document's javascript global scope as the variable `myJSONData`.

### 3) Embed the `.json` file in the document (via `<object>` or `<iframe>`)

When we were discussing earlier, I commented:

> I guess because HTML lacks anything like `<file type="application/json"
>   src="/app/data.json" />` (analogous to `<img src="/app/my-image.png"
>   alt="My Image" />`).

Then, I wondered if that was actually true. It turns out, it's not.

Here's a third way to retrieve the `.json` from the server:

---

#### Using `HTML5 <embed>`

`<embed>` appears to be locked and its `contentDocument` inaccessible. Not clear why.

---

#### Using `HTML5 <object>`

**HTML:**

```
<object data="/app/data.json" style="display: none"></object>
```

**JS:**

```
<script>
let myObject = document.getElementsByTagName('object')[0];

const getJSONFromObject = () => {
  console.log(myObject.contentDocument.body.textContent);
}

myObject.addEventListener('load', getJSONFromObject);
</script>
```

---

#### Using `HTML5 <iframe>`

**HTML:**

```
<iframe src="/app/data.json" style="display: none"></iframe>
```

**JS:**

```
<script>
let myIframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];

const getJSONFromIframe = () => {
  console.log(myIframe.contentDocument.body.textContent);
}

myIframe.addEventListener('load', getJSONFromIframe);
</script>
```

---

In order of personal preference, my favoured approaches would be:

1. `Fetch` the `.json` file
2. `XHR` the `.json` file
3. Use a `.js` file instead of a `.json` file
4. Embed the `.json` in the document via `<object>`

Comment: But isn't the purpose of XHR/fetch is to get global files? In our scenario its local, why would I request my own server for a file? Isn't it like walking all the way to the post office to send a letter to your brother who is at the next room?

Comment: I guess because HTML lacks anything like `<file type="application/json" src="/app/data.json" />` (analogous to `<img src="/app/my-image.png" alt="My Image" />`).

Comment: There is nothing such as `<file>`; however, you can use a `<script>` tag and it works without parsing the contents of the JSON.

Comment: Your answer is exactly that "hacky workaround" that I described in my question, which is sadly nothing new, I am asking for the CORRECT way to do it.

Comment: Can you explain why is fetch needed for a local file?

Comment: Sorry If I sounded "short-tempered" there, but I did actually mention that I added a variable assignment "prefix" before my JSON data, which is exactly what you mentioned. Thanks for the effort, I think I'll stick to fetch till I find a quenching answer.

Comment: @aelmosalamy - I've written up the third option above (after a lot of experimentation). I couldn't get `<embed>` to work, but I managed to import the `.json` into the document with both `<object>` and `<iframe>`.

Comment: Thank you, I tried iframe and it works like a breeze, but it's a bit in-intuitive, guess I will stick to XHR for now over fetch due to IE 9-11 compatibility. Thanks again mate!

Comment: You're most welcome. I added a final touch above for future visitors - the `<object>` or `<iframe>` should be styled (either inline or in the linked CSS file) with `display: none` to speed up the page rendering time and avoid any unwanted artifacts appearing on the page.