# I have been trying to use Fetch to get data from an external json file with react but kept getting errors

Tags: reactjs

i keep getting this errors in my console

index.js:1375 SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

here is my code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Users extends Component {
  state = {};
  ftUsers() {
    fetch("./components/data/users1.json")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((resData) => {
        console.log(resData.res);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Users Lists</h2>
        <p>{this.ftUsers()}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Users;
```

Comment: Is this a local JSON file? Can you update your question to include it? Run it through a [JSON linter](https://jsonlint.com/) to validate it? "<" isn't a valid starting character.

Answer (score 0):

Refer the link [Relative paths with fetch in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36369082/relative-paths-with-fetch-in-javascript)

When you are using fetch the file should be served via the server. So correct the path of url.

If your json file is inside components/data and you are serving your file from the root folder. The fetch path should be according to this.

```
fetch("components/data/users1.json")
```

Relative paths are used for imports in React. Not AJAX requests.